# R missing() with variable names

Tags: r, function, arguments

In R 3.0.2 the missing() function can tell us whether or not a formal parameter is missing.

How can one avoid hardcoding the variable name passed into missing?  e.g. in

```
demoargs <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
    f <- formals(demoargs)  # Capture formal arguments
    formalNames <- names(f) # get variable names: a, b, d
    ...   
}
```

I would like to be able to check for missing formals without doing this in a hardcoded manner, e.g.:

```
missing(formalNames[1])  # returns invalid use of missing!
```

as opposed to missing(d) for the purpose of iterating over a large number of optional arguments that are handled in a limited number of manners.  I had hoped that get or as.name my put me on the right track but this does not seem to be the case.

Alternatively, I suspect that I could do this with the vararg arguments (...), but it would be nice for the caller to be able to inspect the acceptable optional arguments by examining the function declaration.

Thanks,
Marie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably first tried something like `missing(as.name(formalNames[1]))` or `missing(formalNames[1])` and found that they do not work.

The reason they don't is that `missing()` is one of those odd functions -- `library()` and `debug()` are a couple of  others -- that will accept as an argument either a name or a character representation of a name. That's 'nice' in the sense that `missing(a)` and `missing("a")` will both check whether the function call included a supplied argument `a`; it's not so nice when you do `missing(formalNames[1])` and it goes off to look for a non-existent argument named `formalNames[1]`.

The solution is to use `do.call()`, which evaluates the elements of its second argument *before* passing them on to the function given in its first argument. Here's what you  might do:

```
demoargs <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
    formalNames <- names(formals()) # get variable names: a, b, d
    do.call(missing, list(formalNames[1]))
}

## Try it out
demoargs(a=42)
# [1] FALSE
demoargs()
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can build the call `missing("a")` and then evaluate it, it can be done in different ways :

```r
demoargs1 <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
  formalNames <- names(formals())
  eval(bquote(missing(.(formalNames[1]))))   
}
demoargs1(3)
#> [1] FALSE
demoargs1()
#> [1] TRUE

demoargs2 <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
  formalNames <- names(formals())
  eval(substitute(missing(X), list(X = formalNames[1])))   
}
demoargs2(3)
#> [1] FALSE
demoargs2()
#> [1] TRUE

demoargs3 <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
  formalNames <- names(formals())
  eval(call("missing", formalNames[1]))   
}
demoargs3(3)
#> [1] FALSE
demoargs3()
#> [1] TRUE

demoargs4 <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
  formalNames <- names(formals())
  eval(as.call(c(quote(missing), formalNames[1])))
}
demoargs4(3)
#> [1] FALSE
demoargs4()
#> [1] TRUE
```

Another way is to check if the argument is in the call:

```
demoargs5 <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
  formalNames <- names(formals())
  formalNames[1] %in% names(match.call()[-1])
}
demoargs5(3)
#> [1] TRUE
demoargs5()
#> [1] FALSE
```

Let's add Josh's proposal to the batch and benchmark them:

```
demoargs_josh <- function(a=3, b=2, d) {
  formalNames <- names(formals())
  do.call(missing, list(formalNames[1]))
}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  demoargs_josh(),
  demoargs1(),
  demoargs2(),
  demoargs3(),
  demoargs4(),
  demoargs5(),times = 100000)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>             expr  min   lq      mean median   uq    max neval   cld
#>  demoargs_josh()  2.5  3.1  5.237294    3.5  4.4 7389.8 1e+05 a    
#>      demoargs1() 11.7 13.4 21.198503   14.0 19.0 5708.1 1e+05     e
#>      demoargs2()  3.1  3.7  6.158610    4.0  5.1 6628.5 1e+05   c  
#>      demoargs3()  2.8  3.3  5.465650    3.7  4.6 2936.4 1e+05 ab   
#>      demoargs4()  2.9  3.5  5.712464    3.8  4.9 2104.8 1e+05  b   
#>      demoargs5()  5.1  6.2 10.056112    6.7  8.7 6204.4 1e+05    d
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

using `do.call()` seems slightly faster but using `call()` or `as.call()` shows very similar performance.