# Testing multiple missing arguments

Tags: r

Say I have a function with 26 arguments (all optional) which **must** default to `NULL`

```
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o , p,
                          q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {
...
}
```

I could test each like so for instance

```
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o , p,
                          q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {

if(missing(a)) a <- NULL
if(missing(b)) b <- NULL
...
}
```

or I could have them default to `NULL`

```
missingStuff <- function (a = NULL, b = NULL, c = NULL, d = NULL, e = NULL,
                          f = NULL, g = NULL, h = NULL, i = NULL, j = NULL, 
                          k = NULL, l = NULL, m = NULL, n = NULL, o = NULL,
                          p = NULL, q = NULL, r = NULL, s = NULL, t = NULL,
                          u = NULL, v = NULL, w = NULL, x = NULL, y = NULL,
                          z = NULL) {
...
}
```

But these two options are *tedious* and rather *messy*. For the life of me I cannot find a way to do this properly. Surely this could be done in a more practical manner using `formals()` perhaps

This does not work, it assigns everything to `NULL` regardless of the `if` statement

```
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o , p,
                          q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {

  lapply(formals(), function(x) {
    if(missing(x)) x <- NULL
    })
}
```

Neither does

```
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o , p,
                          q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {

  lapply(formals(), function(x) {
    if(x == "") x <- NULL
    })
}
```

Despite

```
formals(missingStuff)[1] == ""
   a 
TRUE
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what are you trying to do here exactly

Comment: All arguments must default to `NULL` somehow

Comment: you already did that in `or I could have them default to NULL`

Comment: @mtoto As far as I understand, the OP is looking for a programmatic way to set the default value of all parameters to `NULL`.

Comment: I think there are a couple of quirks. You're calling `missing` from within another function, it may [mix up names and character values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872128/r-missing-with-variable-names) etc. Ugly, but it may work for you: `for (x in setdiff(names(formals()), names(as.list(match.call()[-1])))) assign(x, value=NULL)`.

Comment: How about introducing the `...` argument and test for the presence of arguments?

Comment: I disagree with your claim that explicit assignments are "messy."  It's far clearer to some other user that everything defaults to NULL if it's right up there in the `formals` of your function.   That said, I'm hard-pressed to imagine a function which requires 26 inputs.  That's what `...` is for -- optional args which can be ignored unless called out.  Or alternatively, with that many inputs consider requiring a `list` variable to be passed to your function, and create a default variable full of NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use sys.call ar match.call to extract the passed arguments. 
Then you can set different conditions and update the values you'd like.

```
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o , p,
                      q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {


  # get the names of the passed variables
  var <- names(as.list( sys.call() ))[-1]


  # set all the variables that arent passed to NULL
  for(i in 1:length(setdiff(names(formals(missingStuff)),var))){
    assign(setdiff(names(formals(missingStuff)),var)[i],NULL)
  }

  # set all the arguments that are passed as "" or NULL as NULL
  for(i in 1:length(var[mget(var)=="" | is.null(mget(var))])){
    assign(var[mget(var)==""][i],NULL)
  }

  # print all the values of the arguments
  mget(names(formals(missingStuff)))
}
```

When run for example:

```
missingStuff(a=,b=5,c=NULL)
```

You'll get a print of the arguments:

```
> missingStuff(a=,b=5,c=NULL)
$a
NULL

$b
[1] 5

$c
NULL

$d
NULL
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try `eval`:

```
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f)
{
  lapply(names(formals()), function(x)
  { eval(parse(text = paste0("if (missing(",x,")) {assign(\"",x,"\",NULL)}")), envir = parent.env(environment())) } )

  # print them
  for(name in names(formals())) { print(get(name)) }
}

missingStuff(a=1,f=4)
```

When executed, gives:

```
> missingStuff(a=1,f=4)
[1] 1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. We filter the formals to keep arguments not found in the call, thus we get a list of missing arguments, then assign `NULL` to all of them, and we assign the list elements to the local environment.

```r
missingStuff <- function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o , p,
                          q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) {
  fmls <- formals()
  missing_fmls <- fmls[!names(fmls) %in% names(match.call()[-1])]
  missing_fmls[] <- list(NULL)
  list2env(missing_fmls, environment())

  print(b)
  print(r)

}
missingStuff()
#> NULL
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>